# Git pull --rebase when push

Tags: git, push, rebase, pull

I'd like to know if it would be possible with git to auto `pull --rebase` when doing `git push` ?

I mean if `git push` is rejected, automatically do a `git pull --rebase` and then `git push` again so I don't need to do that manually each time someone push before me.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here: How can Git do an automatic rebase followed by push when rebasing may likely introduce merge conflicts which will have to be resolved by hand?  I could see the initiation of the rebase happening automatically though.

Comment: I agree with you, it can't work every time. The idee is: try to make a standard pull-rebase. If there are conflicts, of course, stop the workflow and ask user for a manual merge.

Comment: This can definitely be done, because, for example, Eclipse has the option to do pulling with a rebase stategy.  You could write a batch script to do the same.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a .sh file?

Comment: I was thinking about something more cross platform friendly (I'm working on windows)

Comment: A prepush hook maybe?

Comment: create an alias with `git pull -r && git push` and it should do the work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to do

```
git pull --rebase && git push
```

Maybe you want to create an alias for this

```
git config --global alias.rbpush '! git pull --rebase && git push'
```

and then invoke it using:

```
git rbpush
```

But keep in mind that the rebase might cause conflits that you have to solve. And while you are solving the conflicts another developer might push in the meanwhile.

[EDIT] Remove "_" in alias's name because git doesn't parse them.